# Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de XXXX

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo este `query` que ejecuto en `SSMS` y corre perfectamente bien:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT ca.cod_parte,
       p.descripcion, 
       ( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total,
       p.unidad,
       dt1.precio
FROM   transa_det1 td
       INNER JOIN transa ta
               ON ta.boleta = td.boleta 
       INNER JOIN Casiller ca ON ca.rollo=td.rollo
       INNER JOIN Partes P ON p.cod_parte=ca.cod_parte
       INNER JOIN Det_materiales dt1 ON dt1.cod_parte=p.cod_parte AND dt1.rollo=td.rollo
       OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS ret 
                    FROM   devol_det1 d1
                           INNER JOIN devol d
                                   ON d1.boleta = d.boleta 
                    WHERE  d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden=ta.orden)c 
where ta.orden = 'GOER-4032'
```

al querer usar el mismo query en C# se me presenta un error:

```
public DataTable listadoRollosOrdeneSumario(string ordenEntrada)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            datasetSumarioOrdenesxsd dsSumario = new datasetSumarioOrdenesxsd();

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SIKOR;Integrated Security=True"))
            {

                cnn.Open();
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT ca.cod_parte, p.descripcion,( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total,p.unidad,dt1.precio " +
                    "FROM transa_det1 td " +
                    "INNER JOIN transa ta ON ta.boleta = td.boleta" +
                    "INNER JOIN Casiller ca ON ca.rollo = td.rollo" +
                    "INNER JOIN Partes P ON p.cod_parte = ca.cod_parte" +
                    "INNER JOIN Det_materiales dt1 ON dt1.cod_parte = p.cod_parte AND dt1.rollo = td.rollo" +
                    "OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS ret " +
                    "FROM devol_det1 d1" +
                    "INNER JOIN devol d ON d1.boleta = d.boleta" +
                    "WHERE d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden = ta.orden)c" +
                    "WHERE ta.orden = @oo";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oo",ordenEntrada);
                    SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    ds.Fill(dt);
                    dsSumario.Tables.Add(dt);

                }

                cnn.Close();


            }

            return dt;
        }
```

En la linea `ds.Fill(dt)`  me lanza el siguiente error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de
>   'apply'. Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'd1'.'

Que esta mal en el codigo de `C#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando vas armar una query en un string no usas el `+` para unir cada linea, usas el multi-line del string con el `@`

```
cnn.Open();

string sqlQuery = @"SELECT ca.cod_parte, p.descripcion,( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total,p.unidad,dt1.precio 
                    FROM transa_det1 td
                        INNER JOIN transa ta ON ta.boleta = td.boleta
                        INNER JOIN Casiller ca ON ca.rollo = td.rollo
                        INNER JOIN Partes P ON p.cod_parte = ca.cod_parte
                        INNER JOIN Det_materiales dt1 ON dt1.cod_parte = p.cod_parte AND dt1.rollo = td.rollo
                        OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS ret
                                    FROM devol_det1 d1
                                    INNER JOIN devol d ON d1.boleta = d.boleta
                                    WHERE d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden = ta.orden) c
                                    WHERE ta.orden = @oo";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cnn))
{
 //resto codigo
```

de esta forma no tendras problemas con los espacios y podras definir una correcta identacion para que el sql quede mas prolijo y entendible

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan los espacios al final de las concatenaciones:

```
public DataTable listadoRollosOrdeneSumario(string ordenEntrada)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            datasetSumarioOrdenesxsd dsSumario = new datasetSumarioOrdenesxsd();

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SIKOR;Integrated Security=True"))
            {

                cnn.Open();
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT ca.cod_parte, p.descripcion,( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total,p.unidad,dt1.precio " +
                    "FROM transa_det1 td " +
                    "INNER JOIN transa ta ON ta.boleta = td.boleta " +
                    "INNER JOIN Casiller ca ON ca.rollo = td.rollo " +
                    "INNER JOIN Partes P ON p.cod_parte = ca.cod_parte " +
                    "INNER JOIN Det_materiales dt1 ON dt1.cod_parte = p.cod_parte AND dt1.rollo = td.rollo " +
                    "OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS ret " +
                    "FROM devol_det1 d1 " +
                    "INNER JOIN devol d ON d1.boleta = d.boleta " +
                    "WHERE d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden = ta.orden)c " +
                    "WHERE ta.orden = @oo";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oo",ordenEntrada);
                    SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    ds.Fill(dt);
                    dsSumario.Tables.Add(dt);

                }

                cnn.Close();


            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por detectar y exponer el error. Pero ante problemas tipograficos como el de la pregunta, lo correcto es señalarlo en un comentario y votar para cerrar la pregunta como No relacionado > fallo tipografico., Un saludo!